# How to get resource string array in android?

Tags: java, android, resources, android-xml, android-resources

I have more than 10000 city names and i want to show in ListView. I stored those names as city.xml file in `res/values folder`

like below

```
<resources>
<string-array name="city"> 
<item>  chennai, India </item>
<item>  Spring Creek , Australia </item>
.
.
```

Then I create a ArrayAdapter and populate to listView like this.

```
String[] cityDetails = res.getStringArray(R.array.city); // <-- getting Error in this line
myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.ap_details_row, R.id.aNameTV, cityDetails );
myLV.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

It works fine in API level 13 and above devices. But below API level 13 devices, I get the following error.

```
 W/dalvikvm(306): ReferenceTable overflow (max=512)
 W/dalvikvm(306): Last 10 entries in JNI local reference table:
  W/dalvikvm(306):   502: 0x45fbb330 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   503: 0x45fbb388 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   504: 0x45fbb3e0 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   505: 0x45fbb438 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   506: 0x45fbb498 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   507: 0x45fbb4f8 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   508: 0x45fbb558 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   509: 0x45fbb5d0 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   510: 0x45fbb638 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   511: 0x45fbb698 cls=Ljava/lang/String; (28 bytes)
  W/dalvikvm(306): JNI local reference table summary (512 entries):
  W/dalvikvm(306):     3 of Ljava/lang/Class; 164B (2 unique)
  W/dalvikvm(306):   507 of Ljava/lang/String; 28B (507 unique)
  W/dalvikvm(306):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 28B
  W/dalvikvm(306):     1 of [Ljava/lang/String; 37436B
  W/dalvikvm(306): Memory held directly by tracked refs is 51988 bytes
  E/dalvikvm(306): Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)
  I/dalvikvm(306): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
  I/dalvikvm(306):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0
  I/dalvikvm(306):   | sysTid=306 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008
  I/dalvikvm(306):   | schedstat=( 1050455605 562911400 652 )
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getArrayStringResource(Native Method)
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceStringArray(AssetManager.java:186)
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:381)
  I/dalvikvm(306):   at com.mypro.main.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:184)
 I/dalvikvm(306):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 E/dalvikvm(306): VM aborting
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is somewhat similar to your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372373/referencetable-overflow-max-512-jni

Comment: @Rosalie yes. but they are using Android NDK